# If class name and window location match, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the class name clicked has the same name as the current URL, equate to `true`. Here is how I would currently have it:

```
$('a.archive').click(function(){
   if (window.location == www.google.com/archive.php)
  // do something
else {
  // do default
     }
});
```

However, I don't want to write a different URL in each `if` statement. I'd like to find a way of matching the location: www.google.com/**archive**.php with the class name that was clicked: .**archive**

So ideally I could write this, instead:

```
$('a.archive').click(function(){
 if (URLandClassNameMatch).
      // do something
    else {
      // do default
         }
});
```

Comment: not clear what do u mean by 'more automated'

Comment: So I don't need to state a different URL in each `if` statement. Find a way of matching the location: www.google.com/`archive`.php with the class name .`archive`.

Comment: provide some markup and better explanation of objectives. Can compare `href` to `url` on page load, or within clcik handler

Comment: The problem is that you have some `$("a.className")` and want them to be totally automatic? Please explain the full problem, it's not clear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think something like this?

```
$("a").click(function(ev)
{
   var classes = ($(this).attr('class') || "").split(" ");
   $.each(classes, function(index, value)
   {
       if (window.location.href.indexOf("/"+value+".php") != -1)
          // doSomething
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to look up some of that code (`ev`, `indexOf`, `index, value`,), but that looks like it!

Comment: @tmyie - I've forgotten to include the split. Edited

Answer (score 0):

This might be what u want

http://jsfiddle.net/KDLjf/82/

Check this fiddle as well for ur comment

http://jsfiddle.net/KDLjf/83/

```
$('a.archive').click(function(){
    var url="www.google.com/"+$(this).attr('class')+".php";
    alert(url);
 if (window.location==url) // so if they match, it equates to true.
 {
 alert('Matched')
 }
      // do something
    else {
        alert('Not Matched')
      // do default
         }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Rather than use `www.google.com`, could I use `window.location` in some way? To try and keep it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

well as per my understanding I have done something like this

```
var yourclassclass = $('your_id').attr('class');
var regx = new RegExp("[a-z][A-Z].[a-z][A-Z].com/"+yourclassclass+".php");
var URLandClassNameMatch = regx.exec(yourURL.search);
if (URLandClassNameMatch).
   // do something
else {
   // do default
}
```

if you are getting the URL from "window.location" then replace the yourURL with "window.location".